# Multi-Threaded Server/New Object on Each Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, object

In my project I have a server that handles multiple clients that connect to it. Each time a client is connected, a new "Guitar" is created, specific to that client on a new thread. Each "Guitar" is an array of 12 guitar strings, and when a key corresponding to a string is pressed in the client window, that guitar's string is plucked.

I have a method called notePlayed(char key) in my Guitar class that "plucks" the string and adds all of the "plucks" into the combined audio to be played. However, I am running into this error anytime it is called:

```
key pressedj
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.NullPointerException
notePlayed accessed
at Guitar.notePlayed(Guitar.java:29)
at GuitarListener.run(GuitarServer.java:33)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

My guitarserver looks like this:

```
class GuitarListener implements Runnable {
private Socket sock;
private GuitarListenerGui gui;
private Guitar guitar;

public GuitarListener(Socket s, GuitarListenerGui g, Guitar gt) {
    this.sock = s;
    this.gui = g;
    this.guitar = gt;
}

public void run() {
    boolean loop=true;
    try {
        //setting up printwriters and bufferedreaders removed
        System.out.println("key pressed" + key);
        Guitar.notePlayed(key);
        }
```

with the new Guitar and threads created in the GuitarServer class further down

```
String keyboard ="qwertyuiop[]";
            GuitarString[] gStrings = new GuitarString[keyboard.length()];
            Guitar guitar = new Guitar(gStrings, keyboard);
            GuitarListener job = new GuitarListener(serverSocket.accept(), gui, guitar);

            // start a new thread to handle the connection
            Thread t = new Thread(job);
            t.start();
```

and my Guitar class looks like this:

```
public class Guitar {

private static String keyboard;;
private static GuitarString[] gStrings; 

public Guitar (GuitarString[] gStrings, String keyboard){
    this.keyboard=keyboard;
    this.gStrings=gStrings;
}
```

with the for-loop causing the error here:

```
    public static void notePlayed (char key){
  double sample=0.0;
               for (int i=0; i<keyboard.length(); i++){//adds all of the strings to sample to be played
                   sample+=gStrings[i].sample();
```

Sorry about the length of the post, but can anybody point me in the right direction or let me know how far off I am? Thanks in advance. I am happy to answer anymore questions you may have.

In the main function of Guitar I initialize the guitarstrings with this loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<keyboard.length();i++){
        double iNote = 440.0* Math.pow(2, i/12.0);//puts the correct frequency with each string
        System.out.println(iNote);
        gStrings[i] = new GuitarString(iNote);
    }
```

Comment: What IDE are you using? If you are using Eclipse go to your breakpoints and add a breakpoint for Null Pointer Exception to give you a better understanding of what the issue is. Seems like with some good debugging you should be able to figure this out.

Comment: You have a NullPointerException, and it's telling you where. You're trying to use something that is `null`. This is an excellent opportunity to familiarize yourself with the debugger.

Comment: Thanks, I have never really been introduced to the debug tool, but I will definitely try and play around with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 GuitarString[] gStrings = new GuitarString[keyboard.length()];
```

will result in an array of GuitarString objects with the size of `keyboard.length()` all  initialized with `null` value. You have to initialize each GuitarString object in the array before using it in the for loop in the line `sample+=gStrings[i].sample();`

Comment: Thanks for the help clinton, I had to initialize gStrings in the constructor rather than in main